# The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key while trying to communicate on SSLstream on TCP port

Tags: c#, ssl, service, verifone

We are using window service to communicate with client (web application and VeriFone device) on TCP port. Till now we have used network stream to communicate and all was working fine but, now we want to communicate it on SSL stream. We were assuming that there will be a certificate having .cer or .pfx extension but we received few certificates having .crt and .p7b extension from go daddy. While using .crt extension certificate we are getting error “The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.” We got help from MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx). Can anyone help me that how these SSL certificates extensions  will be used in window service.

Comment: What do you mean you "received few certificates...from godaddy"?  Are they signing certs, SSL Server certs, something else?  The server side of an SSL communication needs a cert with a private key--which you need to get from your cert provider.

Comment: @Peter, yes we received 4 certificate files and confused that which one we have to use. We are totally not aware that they are signing or not. Do I really need a certificate with a private key or we need to generate at our end.

Comment: You need to use the right cert for what you are doing.  There should be only one cert for an SSL Server and it should include a private key (e.g. .cer or .pfx extension).  If you don't have one like that, you can't install it on a server; and I recommend asking godaddy for an SSL server cert for *that* server (i.e. has to have the same DNS name as the server--the name the clients will use).